# save token in localStorage and interceptors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

How to save token in localStorage and push token in interceptors for send token to all request, I send data user and token from controller symfony to front end but I am blocked now when I have save token in localStorage and interceptors.

Comment: Please post what you have tried. We need to see code or we cannot reasonably help.

Comment: You should clarify which angular version you're using. As you tagged JavaScript I assume you're still on AngularJS (which is version 1.x)

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "value");
```

To get the value use: `localStorage.getItem("name");`

Comment: And for interceptors haw to save token !?